# Mongodb get field that is part of a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get the field of a MongoDB collection where the field is a substring of a longer string.

Real example:
str = 'forest'

MongoDB Collection:

{id: 1, name: est}

{id: 2, name: ab}

I want to get the first item because `est` is a substring of `forest`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this very efficiently is with MongoDB's [full-text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/). This requires defining a text index type on that particular field.

If you wanted matches that strictly contained your query, check out the [exact-phrase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#exact-phrase) operator.

Comment: I checked it out but it didn't return what I wanted. Even though the string was ```foret```, it still returned ```est```. I want the field to be an exact substring of the initial string instead of searching for a field that is similar to my string.

Comment: @ErgiLaze you need to use the exact match operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#exact-phrase

Comment: I tried that one as well but it doesn't return the substring, only the exact match. If my string is ```forest```, it returns null. If my string is ```est```, it returns the correct one.